# How do I transfer pictures from OneDrive to my laptop?

Tags: onedrive

How do I transfer my pics from one drive into my laptop? I tried downloading but it didn't work and there are too many to do one at a time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has nothing to do with Windows phones.

Answer (score 3):

You can do two things:

You can download the photos using the OneDrive client. Depending on what OS you have installed you just need to set it up (Windows 8, 10) as it's pre-installed. [For Windows 7 or other systems go here](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/download/).

You can also download all pictures [through the browser](http://onedrive.com) as a single zip-file. Go into the folder you'd like to get and click the "download" link in the top bar.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a machine running Windows, the good thing is you have [OneDrive](http://onedrive.live.com) preinstalled, and all you need to do is sign in with your Microsoft Account, and the photos will be downloaded onto your machine.

If you already have Windows running on this laptop you want your pictures on, and have already signed in with your Microsoft account, navigate to your user account's root directory, (**`C:\User\your_username`**), and you will find a folder named **Onedrive**:

[image]

In that folder, all the stuff that is on your OneDrive account will be syncronized into this folder. Everything thats on the cloud is downloaded automatically into this folder, so your photos will be in there as well.

Navigate to a folder named "Pictures", in the Onedrive directory. Under there, you will find all your photos from the cloud in there.

However, If you are using any alternative operating system, you have to visit [onedrive.live.com](http://onedrive.live.com), right click onto a folder that contains the photos you want, and click download, and the contents will be zipped and downloaded as just one compressed file, which you can then extract all the contents after the download has finished:

[image]